# Is it possible to get data that was sent over async connection?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have a client that receives data over tcp and sends it over to another server. I'm trying to make sure that I don't lose any messages if any disconnect happens.
In the `SendCallback` I check if the server was still connected. If the server got disconnected I want to save the message to a list to retry later.

Is there a way to get the string/byte array that failed to send?

```
        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {            
            try
            {
                Socket receiver = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = receiver.EndSend(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's send call back but before you try to call this call back you try to fill your buffer . it's StateObject containing buffer size and socket handler and so on . 
So your answer definitely is YES.
You should read more about asynchronous socket programming in MSDN reference Website.

Comment: Gotcha! Completely forgot I can send the stateObject instead of just the socket. Thanks.